# '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' i am getting error while writing in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    import openpyxl
    import getpass
    import os
    import shutil
    import sys
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
    from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, NamedStyle, Color, PatternFill, Font, Alignment
    from openpyxl.styles import colors
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    import win32com.client as win32
    import xlwings as xw


  REMOVE: All counters that are no longer being used. Check on raw_input, row deletion, and pandas.




 curr_row = 2
    detections = 0
    detections_rem_tmfrm = 0
    pias_needed = 0
    pias_comp = 0
    web_num = "Null"
    int_end_analysis = 0
    int_ptch_analysis = 0


    print(e)



 op = input('\nDo you want to continue? Y/N\n\n').upper()

    if op != "Y":
        sys.exit("\nExiting program.")
    else:
        print("\nContinuing process.")

    #get user name
    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    print("current directory is : " + dirpath)
    foldername = os.path.basename(dirpath)
    print("Directory name is : " + foldername)
    #get current directory
    #os.chdir(foldername % username)
    #os.path.join(foldername,username)
    #Loads Excel sheet with all of the companies' responses recorded. 
    data_file = openpyxl.load_workbook('_Dash_Da.xlsx')

for row in range (2, q1_sheet.max_row+1):
```

Gets value of cell in Column A, Row[whatever int the variable "row" is currently representing]
        curr_opco = q1_sheet['B' + str(row)].value

```
    shutil.copy("_Dash_tem.xlsx", "%s Dash.xlsx" % curr_opco)

print("\nCreated Oco Dash Tem")
col_num_left = 6 
col_num_right = 13
```

for quarter in quarters_arr:

```
    #Keep a placeholder number for the column where this all gets written.
    #This will deprecate through the loop

    print("\n.......Beginning work on %s...\n" % quarter)

    #Iterate through each Op
    for row in range (2, 20):

        print("Current Op: " + curr_op)

        #Gets value of cell in Column A, Row[whatever int the variable "row" is currently representing]
        curr_op = quarter['B' + str(row)].value

        #print(quarter)
        #print(curr_op)

        qtr_title = quarter.title

        #Load current Op's template file
        dashboard = openpyxl.load_workbook('%s Das.xlsx' % curr_op)
        exec_summary = dashboard.worksheets[0]
        endpt_details = dashboard.worksheets[1]
        patching_details = dashboard.worksheets[2]
        privacy_details = dashboard.worksheets[3]
        cloudmon_details = dashboard.worksheets[4]
        critasset_details = dashboard.worksheets[5]
        #Add any new worksheet up here

        #Collect End sey de
        ser_sc_A = quarter['E' + str(row)].value
        cl_sc_A = quarter['F' + str(row)].value
        dev_A_co = quarter['G' + str(row)].value
        ser_sc_S = quarter['I' + str(row)].value
        c_s_S = quarter['J' + str(row)].value
        ds_S_in = quarter['K' + str(row)].value
```

IN this line of code i am getting error('>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int') here i am trying to do some calulation and write it to excel file but here i am getting error

```
AVd = (quarter['E' + str(row)].value +quarter['F' + str(row)].value)
                if AVd > 0:
                    AVvalue = (dev_A_co/ AVd)*100
                elif AVd==0:
                    AVvalue = 100
                #Get current column letters:


    left_col_ltr = (get_column_letter(co

l_num_left))
                        right_col_ltr = (get_column_letter(col_num_right))


                        dashboard.save('%s Dash.xlsx' % curr_op)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AV is not defined and it is being used in if loop. Print output of variable and types to check further.

Comment: thanks for your help but now i am getting error 
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Please print avd and share output, print(type(avd)) as well

Comment: Current Op: J <class 'str'>
Current OpCo: SH <class 'int'> for op it is showing str and for others it is showing int

Comment: What's the value of av and and?

Comment: and for it showing blank  for Op: J and for others it is showing results while printing(AVd)

Comment: And I can see only AVd is defined amd you are using AV in if loop??

Comment: sorry it is my bad i changed it to avd

Comment: nope can you please tell me how to handle blank because it is showing blank

Comment: Use if loop like,  if avd:   , it will execute only when avd is not none.

Comment: can you get me little bit of approach

Comment: Put If avd: above if ave>0 with proper indent